# why double colon will not work in case statement

Tags: amazon-athena

I want to tag host names with '`::'` (this character) to be tagged as cloud and rest everything to 'not cloud'.

I tried using like operator, its not working, my result tags all the host names to not cloud

```
select a.department, count(host_name),
(CASE
   WHEN host_name like '%::%' THEN 'Cloud'
   ELSE 'Not cloud'
END) as cloud_instance
from 
table a
```

Expected output:
If I have this expression `'::'` in my host name then it should appear as cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query does not make sense, because it invokes the `COUNT()` function, a table level function, along with individual row-level columns.  I suspect that this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT
    a.department,
    COUNT(a.host_name) AS dept_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.host_name LIKE '%::%' THEN 1 END) AS cloud_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.host_name NOT LIKE '%::%' THEN 1 END) AS no_cloud_cnt
FROM yourTable a
GROUP BY
    a.department;
```

Here we aggregate by department, and for each department turn out the total count, cloud, and non cloud counts.